# Custom Powershell Provider implementation

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to create a PowerShell Provider that will work like a directory structure.
The root is a web address that returns a text file. This file has a list of items. When each of these items is appended to the end of the original web address, I get another file with another list of items. This goes on recursively until the file does not return any item. So the structure is like:

```
root: 1.2.3.4/test/     -> returns file0
file0: item1, item2, item3

1.2.3.4/test/item1      -> returns file1
1.2.3.4/test/item2      -> returns file2
1.2.3.4/test/item3      -> returns file3

file1: item4, item5
file2: item6
file3: <empty>
```

Since I want to create a navigation like structure, I extended the NavigationCmdletProvider

```
public class TESTProvider : NavigationCmdletProvider
```

I am able to create the new PSDrive as follows:

```
PS c:\> New-PSDrive -Name dr1 -PSProvider TestProvider -Root http://1.2.3.4/v1

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider     Root                                            CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      -------------------
dr1                                    TestProvider  http://1.2.3.4/v1
```

But when I 'cd' to that drive, I get an error:

```
PS c:\> cd dr1:

cd : Cannot find path 'dr1:\' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd dr1:
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dr1:\:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

What method do I have to implement/override to show the prompt as PS dr1:> when I do cd dr1:?
(After this I understand that I will have to override `GetChildItems(string path, bool recurse)` to get item1, item2, item3 listed.)

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but you should look at https://github.com/beefarino/p2f/ or https://github.com/beefarino/simplex - they both make building a provider much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that implementing `IsValidPath`, `ItemExists`, `IsItemContainer`, and `GetChildren` get you to a working state.  This is what I usually start with when I am implementing a navigation provider:

```
[CmdletProvider("MyPowerShellProvider", ProviderCapabilities.None)]
public class MyPowerShellProvider : NavigationCmdletProvider
{

    protected override bool IsValidPath(string path)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override Collection<PSDriveInfo> InitializeDefaultDrives()
    {
        PSDriveInfo drive = new PSDriveInfo("MyDrive", this.ProviderInfo, "", "", null);
        Collection<PSDriveInfo> drives = new Collection<PSDriveInfo>() {drive};
        return drives;
    }

    protected override bool ItemExists(string path)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override bool IsItemContainer(string path)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override void GetChildItems(string path, bool recurse)
    {
        WriteItemObject("Hello", "Hello", true);
    }
}
```